# Google Map Js Api Premium plan limitations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have Google premium account.

I am using google map javascript api for showing map on our website.

**Feature of map like**

1. Load the map
2. Place the markers programmatically with coordinates.coordinates already stored in database. i used those coordinates to place the markers.

so my question is that what is the limitations for above features for premium account? Is there any limit that how may times we can load the map and place the marker.

I have seen some requests limit for directions and other things. but i am not using direction feature.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you use a Premium plan Google Maps JavaScript API map loads will be counted against the purchased map credits. Map load is incurred when you show a map in your application. Interactions like zoom, pan or create new marker are not counted.

There is no daily limit, you can use maps while your map credits are not exhausted.

Client side services (geocoding, directions, distance matrix) and places library will consume your map credits as well.

For more details I can suggest reading the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits